# Как вывести в консоль всё что храниться в файле?

Tags: c++, файлы, ввод, файловый-ввод-вывод

Задача такая: вывести в консоль каждое пятое слово помещенное в файле New2.txt, используя динамическое распределение памяти?

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FILE * ptrFile = fopen("t:\\New2.txt", "r");

    fseek(ptrFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    int n = ftell(ptrFile);
    rewind(ptrFile);    // переместить курсор
    cout << "File size is: " << n << " Bytes!" << endl;

    char *ptrbuffer = new char[n];
    //fread(&ptrFile[n], sizeof ptrFile[n], ptrbuffer.size(), ptrFile);

    for (int i = 1; scanf("%s", n) != EOF; i++)
    {
        if (i % 5 == 0)
            cout << n << endl;
    }


    fclose(ptrFile);
    if (ptrFile)
        delete[] ptrbuffer;
    _getch();
    fclose(ptrFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну попробуйте читать **из файла** - не `scanf("%s", n)`, а `fscanf(ptrFile,"%s", ptrBuffer)`... Только если у вас C++, то почему бы не воспользоваться `string`?

Comment: Как именно мне использовать string? Поместить в него файл из буфера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если требование только "динамическое выделение памяти", а язык С++, я бы делал так:

```
int main()
{
    const int wordSize = 1024;
    ifstream in("new2.txt");
    char *buf = new char[wordSize];
    for(int i = 1; in >> buf; ++i)
        if (i%5==0) cout << buf << " ";
    delete[] buf;
}
```